# FontAwesome Stack Replace on Hover

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

So I've been trying to do a quick animation that replaces an entire span on hover but I can't seem to get it to work. How should I approach going about replacing a span on hover?

```
<h1>I need this replaced...</h1>
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
<h1>to this</h1>
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
<h1>on hover</h1>
```

Sample [CodePen](https://codepen.io/oreo27/pen/pNopxz) here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By changing the `:before` css properties for the twitter on hover you can achieve the output.

```css
span.fa-stack:hover i.fa-twitter:before{content:"\f024"; color:#fff}

span.fa-stack:hover i.fa-square-o:before{content:"\f111"}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1>I need this replaced...</h1>
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, Welome to stackoverflow ;)

Comment: @CharantejGolla this is simple and less complex than using the :nth-child selectors, and solves the question perfectly. However, I'd consider using the nth-child selectors as an example of how the solution can be more flexible to other use-cases.

Comment: @Ant Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome. :)

@Ant
I'll look into that as well. Thanks!

Comment: @oreo27, no problem. Charantej Golla already had a great answer, I just wanted to suggest a way you can make it more dynamic if you need the same functionality for other icons.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this in CSS by combining the `:hover` and `:first-child/:last-child` CSS selectors.

```css
.fa-stack.fa-lg:hover :first-child:before {
  content: "\f111";
}

.fa-stack.fa-lg:hover :last-child:before {
  content: "\f024";
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```